# Remove title and date in jupyter notebook

Tags: titles

I want to download my jupyter notebook as pdf via latex but then I always get the name of the document and the date on the pdf. How can I remove that if it‘s possible? [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! This should probably be asked in a forum for Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter Notebook doesn't actually use LaTeX, but rather MathJax, and most questions about MathJax are off topic here.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL This seems to be about a PDF generated from a notebook, which is then probably created by LaTeX via `pandoc`. That said, you may well be right that e.g. [so] would be a better place to ask, as I suspect you need Jupyter knowledge here, more than LaTeX knowledge.